# How to make one side circular border of widget with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, border

I'm trying to build one side circular border with Container widget in flutter.
I have searched for it but can't get any solution.

```dart
Container(
  width: 150.0,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
    /* border: Border(
      left: BorderSide()
    ),*/
  color: Colors.white
  ),
  child: Text("hello"),
),
```

Comment: Unfortunately, until now you can't shape only one side of the container but similar type of functionality can be achieved by making both the corner of that side with circular radius

Answer (score 171):

Use `BorderRadius.only` and provide the sides

```
return Center(
  child: Container(
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topRight: Radius.circular(40),
      ),
      border: Border.all(
        width: 3,
        color: Colors.green,
        style: BorderStyle.solid,
      ),
    ),
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        "Hello",
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: is there a way to do is this just with a ShapeBorder implementation?

Answer (score 36):

You can achieve this by following code for creating your widget :

```
return Container(
  width: 150.0,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
      topRight: Radius.zero,
      bottomLeft: Radius.zero,
      bottomRight: Radius.zero,
    ),
  ),
  child: Text(
    "hello",
  ),
);
```

This way you can have your top left sided circular border with Container widget in flutter.

Comment: Try to add the output of your code. See the difference between your and another highest voted answer, the main difference is output-screen-shot.

Answer (score 11):

Another way of doing this is to use the **ClipRRect** widget.
Simply wrap your widget with **ClipRRect** and give a *radius*.
**You can specify which corner you want to make round.**

```
ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
      child: Container(
        height: 40,
        width: 40,
        color: Colors.amber,
        child: Text('Hello World!'),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 11):

Also You can do it with 'Shape Function'.

```
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topRight: Radius.circular(15.0),
      topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
    ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

also do can do as follows,

```
 borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
     topLeft: const Radius.circular(30.0),
     bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(30.0),
 ),
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want one side of a container rounded you want to use `BorderRadius.only` and specify which corners to round like this:

```
Container(
          width: 150.0,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(40.0)),
              color: Colors.white),
          child: Text("hello"),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can also set the radius of each side.

```
margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0),
```

**fromLTRB= from Left, Top, Right, Bottom**