# Flutter: rounded corner container

Tags: flutter

i am new to flutter. How can I indent the corners like in the picture? Thanks for answers.
[exapmle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oP3uZ.jpg)

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57304681/9609442

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be checking if the problem you faced asked before. There are tons of sources related to this.

1- There are containers with one rounded border in the example video you provided. To achieve that, check the following code:

```
BoxDecoration(
  color: color,
  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100.0),
  ),
);
```

2- To have multiple containers on top of each other, you need to use the Stack widget like the following:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.90,
      decoration: decoration(Colors.black),
    ),
    Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.70,
      decoration: decoration(Colors.purple),
    ),
    Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
      decoration: decoration(Colors.pink),
    ),
    Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.20,
      decoration: decoration(Colors.white),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Complete code `main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const MyHomePage(),
      );
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.90,
              decoration: decoration(Colors.black),
            ),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.70,
              decoration: decoration(Colors.purple),
            ),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
              decoration: decoration(Colors.pink),
            ),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.20,
              decoration: decoration(Colors.white),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          tooltip: 'Add',
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      );

  BoxDecoration decoration(Color color) => BoxDecoration(
        color: color,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100.0),
        ),
      );
}
```

You can also access the complete source code through [GitHub](https://github.com/BBarisKilic/Stack-OverFlow-Solutions/tree/master/question_72511929).

If you have further questions, please don't hesitate to write in the comments.